# Regex for "Characters Numbers"

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

I need a Regex that matches these Strings:

Test 1
Test 123
Test 1.1 (not required but would be neat)
Test
Test a

But not the following:
Test 1a

I don't  know how this pattern should look like that it allows text or whitespace at the end but not if there is a number before.

I tried this one
`^.*([0-9])$` (matches only `Test 1`, but not for example `Test` or `Test a`)
and this one
`^.*[0-9].$` (matches only `Test 1a`, but not for example `Test` or `Test 1`)
 but they don't match what I need.

Comment: Too unclear. What are the specifications? Try [`^\w+(?:\s+(?:\d+(\.\d+)?|\p{L}+))?$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cw%2b(%3f%3a%5cs%2b(%3f%3a%5cd%2b(%5c.%5cd%2b)%3f%7c%5cp%7bL%7d%2b))%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=Test+1%0d%0aTest+123%0d%0aTest+1.1%0d%0aTest%0d%0aTest+a%0d%0a%0d%0aTest+1a&o=m).

Comment: There will me too many possibilities and exceptions..https://regex101.com/r/pC5wN5/3 works just for now but I suspect it will fail at many places

Comment: To make it more clear: `Test` is a placeholder for any text. @rock321987 yours is what I searched for except for the placeholder.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/pC5wN5/4..
updated link

Comment: @rock321987 **Thank you**. That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for all cases you provided

```
^\w+(\s(\d+(\.\d+)?|[a-z]))?$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pC5wN5/5)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
^  #Start of string
 \w+ #Match any characters until next space or end of string
  (\s #Match a whitespace
     (
       \d+  #Match any set of digits
         (\.\d+)? #Digits after decimal(optional)
         |  #Alternation(OR)
       [a-z] #Match any character
     )
  )? #Make it optional
 $ #End of string
```

If you also want to include capital letters, then you can use

```
^\w+(\s(\d+(\.\d+)?|[A-Za-z]))?$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
^\w+\s+((\d+\.\d+)|(\d+)|([^\d^\s]\w+))?\s*$
```

Comment: can you explain this?

Comment: \w+ will allow any alphanumeric character, \s+ any amount of whitespace, then 3 optional groups, being the first one (\d+.d\+) forcing at least one digit the decimal point and at least one digit after it, the second one is any amount of digits, and finally the last one will allow any alphanumeric character BUT excluding the ones that start with a digit

Answer (score 0):

As per your strings in your question (and your comments):

```
^\w+(\s[a-z]|\s\d+(\.\d+)?)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Another pattern for you to try:

```
^(Test(?:$|\s(?:\d$|[a-z]$|\d{3}|\d\.\d$)))
```

[LIVE DEMO.](https://regex101.com/r/hO9aU4/1)